# Seeking Proof for a Conclusion from Positive Definite Homogeneous Polynomials

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

I am trying to find a proof for the following proposition from multivariate real analysis:

> Suppose that $p$ on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ is a homogeneous polynomial of degree $r$ in $x$ and $p\left(x\right) > 0$ for all $x \neq 0 \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$. Show that there is a $\rho > 0$ such that $p\left(x\right) \geq \rho\lVert x \rVert^{r}$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$.

A homogeneous polynomial of degree $r$ is of the following form:
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\forall x \in \mathbb{R}^{n},\ p\left(x\right) = \sum_{i_{1},i_{2},\dots,i_{r}=1}^{n}a_{i_{1},i_{2},\dots,i_{r}}{x_{i_1}}{x_{i_2}}\dots {x_{i_r}},
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
where $x_{s}$ is the $s$-th element of the vector $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$.

P.S. This proposition serves as the basis for proving a theorem about local extreme points in multivariate real analysis. A hint is provided by the textbook: use the fact that $p$ assumes a minimum on the set $\left\{x \vert \lVert x \rVert = 1\right\}$. I am not sure how to construct the proposition from this starting point. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Consider $p(x/\|x\|)$.

Comment: @ShiveringSoldier Proof provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The homogeneous polynomial of order $r$ is of the following general form:
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
\forall x \in \mathbb{R}^{n},\ p\left(x\right) = \sum_{i_{1},i_{2},\dots,i_{r}=1}^{n}a_{i_{1},i_{2},\dots,i_{r}}{x_{i_1}}{x_{i_2}}\dots {x_{i_r}}.
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

As the set
\begin{equation*}
S = \left\{x \vert x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}, {\lVert x \rVert} = 1\right\}
\end{equation*}
is closed and bounded, and $p$ is continuous, there exists an $x_0 \in S$ ($\lVert x_{0}\rVert = 1$) such that
\begin{equation*}
\forall x \in S,\ p\left(x\right) \geq p\left(x_0\right)
\end{equation*}
Let $\rho = p\left(x_{0}\right)$. As $p$ is positive definite, we have $\rho > 0$. Then for all $x \neq 0$, we have
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
p\left(\frac{x}{{\lVert x \rVert}}\right) &= \sum_{i_{1},i_{2},\dots,i_{r}=1}^{n}a_{i_{1},i_{2},\dots,i_{r}}{\frac{x_{i_1}}{{\lVert x \rVert}}}{\frac{x_{i_2}}{{\lVert x \rVert}}}\dots {\frac{x_{i_r}}{{\lVert x \rVert}}}\\
&= \frac{1}{{\lVert x \rVert}^{r}}\sum_{i_{1},i_{2},\dots,i_{r}=1}^{n}a_{i_{1},i_{2},\dots,i_{r}}{x_{i_1}}{x_{i_2}}\dots {x_{i_r}}\\
& = \frac{1}{{\lVert x \rVert}^{r}}p\left(x\right) \geq \rho,
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
and considering the trivial case where ${\lVert x \rVert} = 0$, we have
\begin{equation*}
\forall x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}, p\left(x\right) \geq \rho {\lVert x \rVert}^{r}.
\end{equation*}
And the existential proof is constructed with such a $\rho$.